# How can I create a script that picks up where it left off in case of failure?

Tags: ruby, shell, scripting, rake

I'm working on a script automating the creation of a number of resources in AWS (in addition to some other tasks), but it is very time consuming to develop and test because I can go all the way to the end only to have the script fail, and then I have to correct the error and run the script again.

Are there any shell scripting tools (unix or ruby or even Windows) where I can start the script in the middle in the event of a failure? Maybe there is some way to get `rake` to run a task without all the dependent tasks?

Update:

To clarify, I'm not looking for anything sophisticated with persisting state between invocations; I'm talking about writing a simple shell script with maybe a few dozen sequential steps that each take a long time. In other words, if the script blows up on step 10, I want to start the script again on step 10 without having to rerun all of the previous steps.

Comment: Ruby doesn't support that, nor do any other languages I know of. There is a Perl "executable", which is based on core-dumps, but that always starts at the beginning of the application, not at an arbitrary position with all interpreter state intact. It would be highly invasive to write code that constantly monitored, and saved, the variable state of a running program. While it'd be possible, the program would be really slow and unusable in a production environment, at least with the current speed of computers. Besides, if the program crashed, how would you fix the problem and restart?

Comment: Really it comes down to you needing to architect your application to allow jumping into a particular routine without any prior routines having been run.

Answer (score 0):

You need someway to persist your state of progress as you go, so you know where to start again.

That persistence could be a million things, though.  It could be a database you connect to, a file you write to, a memcached server.

So it really depends on what you are doing, what data you need to record, and what data persistence you have access to.

---

If you had a database to store records in, this would be as simple as somehting like:

```
MyThing.where(uploaded: false).each do |thing|
  thing.upload!
  thing.update_attribute uploaded: true
end
```

If that fails half way through, it picks up where it left off because it's marking the complete records as it goes.

Comment: I've done similar things with big RSS aggregators, that marked the progress as feeds were updated, so if it died it could pick up where it left off. But, that's not really any different than starting at the normal beginning of an app, it's just running with a reduced number of records to work on.

Comment: @theTinMan Do you expect the script to automagically reduce the workload it is supposed to do? An error is an error. Self healing applications are some dream of the future.

Comment: I don't expect the script to do anything but run. How it runs is dependent on the developer. I've written code that had to process thousands of feeds and it could recover after being stopped. If it was a bug it might crash but after fixing it I could restart it and it would take off on the same feed it'd been processing. It's possible to restart at a predefined point but not an arbitrary point.

Comment: I do remember talks and demos of Dylan, out of Apple, years ago, and I think they said it had the ability to restart after halting on an error, and having new code injected. It was probably a risky step because the variable state could possibly be screwed up at that point.

Answer (score 0):

A common lightweight way is to use log files.

Basically you write for every executed entry a line into a log file.

For example:

- `<some_id> OK`
- `<some_id> ERROR <some_reason>`

This way you can get the last "valid state" by executing `grep OK /tmp/script.log | tail -n 1` or all errors with `grep ERROR /tmp/script.log`

One benefit of this solution is that you can read all lines and just call `#.to_i` on them. This way you will get id quite easily.

If you have a couple of million entries your file will get quite bit, but you can throw it away afterwards.

Comment: That's not going to help restart an application, which was at a particular step before it died/crashed/was killed.

Comment: Well it is. 1. You have to fix your app when you see it crashed and then you can run it on all ids that have failed. Or restart at the last id that got executed. My approach is very light weight and not as sophisticated as filling a database, but is available on every computer.